# Is there a way to enter a value on the webpage with the HTML shown?

Tags: vba, webautomation

Im trying to enter a value with web automation. Can I enter values with the HTML in the screenshot?

```
Set objinputs = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each ele In objinputs
    If ele.Class Like "css-9hvios-Input-textInputBaseClass e1tcuc7s0" Then
        ele.Value = ws.Range("A1").Value
    End If
Next
```

Here is a snip of the HTML
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Puxif.png)

Comment: There is no screenshot. Also, please use the snippet tool via [edit] to insert the relevant html rather than a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

**Your code:**

You want `className` not `class`. You can use `Like` but then you probably want an `Exit For` after successful.

```
For Each ele In objinputs
    If ele.ClassName Like "css-9hvios-Input-textInputBaseClass e1tcuc7s0" Then
        ele.Value = ws.Range("A1").Value
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

---

**Alternative:**

Assuming you want to match first `input` element with that class name it is more efficient, and quicker, if you use a css [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors):

```
objIE.querySelector("input.css-9hvios-Input-textInputBaseClass.e1tcuc7s0").value = ws.Range("A1").Value
```

No need for a loop. The dot "." is the class selector followed by the class name.

---

**Refinements:**

You may be able to shorten by removing the leading [tag/type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors) (`input`)

```
objIE.querySelector(".css-9hvios-Input-textInputBaseClass.e1tcuc7s0").value =ws.Range("A1").Value
```

You may be able to further shorten by removing one of the compound class names (the space in the original class name means there is more than one class present. In css you then join the classes by replacing the space with a dot.

```
objIE.querySelector(".css-9hvios-Input-textInputBaseClass").value =ws.Range("A1").Value
```

The classes names look dynamic however so you may need a positional match.

Comment: Here is a picture of the HTML with the highlght the element I am trying to get to  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hEwt.png

Comment: try the above first